# Unwrapping Compound Data with Django REST Framework Serializers

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

If I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name_first = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_middle = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    name_last = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    name_suffix = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    favorite_color = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and I want to deserialize data that is sent as this:

```
"name": {
            "prefix": "",
            "first": "John",
            "middle": "S",
            "last": "Smith",
            "suffix": ""
        },
  "favorite_color": "blue"
```

How do I do that in the Django REST framework? I would prefer to not have to introduce a `Name` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the `from_native` method on your serializer, modifying the `data` dictionary so that it matches your model before the Django REST framework uses it to create an instance:

```
class SubjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subject

    def from_native(self, data, files):
        name_fields = data.pop('name', {})
        for key, val in name_fields.items():
            new_key = 'name_{0}'.format(key)
            data[new_key] = val
        return super(SubjectSerializer, self).from_native(data, files)
```

Note that this doesn't do any validation on the format of the incoming data, so depending on your situation you may need to guard against someone supplying something other than a dictionary. For example, the following data would cause an exception:

```
"name": "John Smith",
"favorite_color": "blue"
```